# Installation failed with standard install instructions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, django-cms, amazon-linux-2

Following the instructions in the documentation, I attempt to create my new project, and get the following error:

EDIT: I should not post questions late at night. Added more detail to the terminal output. Prior to this, I verified pip was upgraded, djangocms-installer is installed and the virtualenv was installed.

```
(djangoenv) [ec2-user@web01 ~]$ djangocms jbi
Creating the project
Please wait while I install dependencies
If I am stuck for a long time, please check for connectivity / PyPi issues
Dependencies installed
Creating the project
The installation has failed.


*****************************************************************

Check documentation at https://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.io

*****************************************************************

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/djangoenv/bin/djangocms", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/ec2-user/djangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 44, in execute
    django.setup_database(config_data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/djangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/django/__init__.py", line 353, in setup_database
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, env=env, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/ec2-user/djangoenv/bin/python', '-W', 'ignore', 'manage.py', 'migrate']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Using Django inside a virtual environment created on an AWS EC2 instance, running Amazon Linux 2. I'm OK with burning the instance down and using another distro if the issue is the distro.

Comment: Please Edit your question to show what you were doing to create this problem, so that we can try to recreate the situation.

Comment: Edited to include that I was running the djangocms jbi command.

Comment: How come you're trying to do a fresh install straight onto an EC2 instance and not locally? Typically you'd setup locally, get the project working as it needs to and then deploy it to AWS. We can't really help with that error because the reason the migrate has failed isn't being reported to the main process.